# How to compile eigen with AVX instructions

Tags: c++, eigen, simd, avx

I have been having trouble finding documentation on how I can compile the eigen library to utilize AVX instructions? How can I best take advantage of a modern processor in eigen?

Comment: If you can use compile-time flags to make binaries that won't run on *non*-AVX CPUs, compile with `gcc -march=native -O3 -ffast-math`.  I think Eigen checks `#ifdef __AVX__`.

Comment: What is the supported way of adding the flags? Should I edit the Makefile generated after running cmake?

Comment: Eigen is header only, so there is nothing to compile/configure on Eigen's side. You have to configure your own project to enable AVX. If your project is cmake-based, then you can do `cmake . -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-march native"`.

Comment: ... or add it to the CMakeLists.txt with `target_compile_options`